# How can I call a function from another contract with it's reference | TypeError: contract.functionName is not a function

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai

I've two smart contracts in my hardhat environment, really small. They are given below:

```
contract Parent {
    Child[] public domainRegistries;

    function createChild() public returns (Child) {
        Child child = new Child();
        domainRegistries.push(child);
        return child;
    }
}

contract Child {

    function sayHello() public {
        console.log("hello world?!!")
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to test them, simply. Like this:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';

interface Parent {
    waitForDeployment: () => any;
    createChild: () => any;
}

describe('Parent', () => {

    let Parent;
    let parent: Parent;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        Parent = await ethers.getContractFactory("Parent");
        await ethers.getSigners();
        parent = await Parent.deploy();
        await parent.waitForDeployment();
    });

    it('child should have said hello', async () => {
        const child = await parent.createChild();
        await child.sayHello();
    });
});
```

But it gives me: **`TypeError: child.sayHello is not a function`**

So I tried logging it in the console, it gave me this:

```
ContractTransactionResponse {
  provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
    _hardhatProvider: LazyInitializationProviderAdapter {
      _providerFactory: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      _emitter: [EventEmitter],
      _initializingPromise: [Promise],
      provider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter]
    },
    _networkName: 'hardhat',
    _blockListeners: [],
    _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
    _eventListeners: []
  },
  blockNumber: 11,
  blockHash: '0xaebcfc0604f012241b75e95f3b226a8406640e3b9e3ff279333eb727ac82fc7c',
  index: undefined,
  hash: '0x9c9221b79fd2db92a7b2520030ebdba4151b5e1702dd8c1d417d6398035350e6',
  type: 2,
  to: '0x8A791620dd6260079BF849Dc5567aDC3F2FdC318',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  nonce: 10,
  gasLimit: 30000000n,
  gasPrice: 1242412728n,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1000000000n,
  maxFeePerGas: 1484825456n,
  data: '0x0ff86c87',
  value: 0n,
  chainId: 31337n,
  signature: Signature { r: "0xd7296e84eebf632c72bfd3af0ff622bd0513d404bc3f94376b1888966f5d6470", s: "0x798794ca00251e4f1c95611011ec9325ca4b92ea72567ad23bb6c8e91f7def35", yParity: 1, networkV: null },
  accessList: []
}
```

**How can I resolve this??**

Comment: The function `createChild()` executes in a transaction, so its return value isn't available. The way to fix this is to emit an event with the child address and create the child object from that event.